# Is it possible to force MapKit to show all annotations without clustering?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

I have two classes that both conform to `MKAnnotation`, and I was wondering, is there a way to force `MapKit` to not cluster the annotation when a user zooms out and display all annotations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set MKAnnotation's `clusteringIdentifier` to nil.

e.g.

```
class BikeView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        willSet {
            if let bike = newValue as? Bike {
                clusteringIdentifier = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've set the `clusteringIdentifier` to nil but still markers disappear when zoomed out.

Comment: I have posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685469/disabling-mkmapview-clustering-annotations-automatically?noredirect=1#comment84370793_48685469). could you please take a look? thank you

Comment: This seems to work if you subclass MKPinAnnotationView but not MKMarkerAnnotationView. Is there anyway to disable clustering without losing the functionality of the markerview?

Answer (score 8):

The mentioned solution didn't work for me, but **this solution worked**:

```
final class CarPinMarkerView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
  override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
    willSet {
        displayPriority = MKFeatureDisplayPriority.required
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You solved my problem!