# Disabling MKMapView clustering annotations automatically

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I have an MKMapView in my App and I've added couple of annotations to it. the problem I am facing is that whenever the map is zoomed out the annotations are clustered automatically. How do I disable this automatic clustering? I am adding couple of screenshots to demonstrate.[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48473227/is-it-possible-to-force-mapkit-to-show-all-annotations-without-clustering) by setting the `clusteringIdentifier` of `MKAnnotation` to nil like this

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "marker")            annotationView?.isHidden = false
    annotationView?.clusteringIdentifier = nil
    return annotationView
}
```

but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: You need to define subclass of MKMarkerAnnotationView and set the `clusteringIdentifier` to nil. See also Apple's sample code https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/MapKit-Sample.zip

Comment: I've described alternative solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49020023/mapkit-annotations-disappearing