# MapKit Annotations Disappearing

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I have an array of latitudes and another array of longitudes that I add to an array of type CLLocationCoordinate2D. I then use the new array to annotate multiple points on the map. Some, or most, or maybe even all of the annotations are displaying on the map but as I zoom in (yes, zoom IN), some of the annotations disappear, then come back, or dont.  Any ideas on how to keep them all visible?  This is behavior I would expect while zooming out, not in.

Here is the code i'm using for what i've described above.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MultiMapVC: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var multiEventMap: MKMapView!

var latDouble = Double()
var longDouble = Double()
let manager = CLLocationManager()
var receivedArrayOfLats = [Double]()
var receivedArrayOfLongs = [Double]()
var locations = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations uLocation: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation = uLocation[0]
    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.3, 0.3)
    let usersLocation = userLocation.coordinate
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(usersLocation, span)
    multiEventMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    manager.distanceFilter = 1000
    self.multiEventMap.showsUserLocation = true
}

func multiPoint() {

    var coordinateArray: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
    print ("Received Longitude Count = \(receivedArrayOfLongs.count)")
    print ("Received Latitude Count = \(receivedArrayOfLats.count)")
    if receivedArrayOfLats.count == receivedArrayOfLongs.count {
        for i in 0 ..< receivedArrayOfLats.count {
            let eventLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(receivedArrayOfLats[i], receivedArrayOfLongs[i])
            coordinateArray.append(eventLocation)
            print (coordinateArray.count)
        }
    }

    for events in coordinateArray {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: events.latitude, longitude: events.longitude)
        multiEventMap.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    multiPoint()
        }


override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    multiEventMap.removeFromSuperview()
    self.multiEventMap = nil

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: Please share your code of viewFor annotation method

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, it appears to be only present in iOS 11.

Comment: I updated to include all the code from my VC..  I don't have a viewForAnnotation method though.

Comment: It is still happens on iOS 13.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

NiltiakSivad's solution works but it reverts to the old iOS 10 look. If you want to keep the new iOS 11 balloon markers for iOS 11 and use the old pin look only for older iOS versions then you can implement the delegate method as below:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let reuseIdentifier = "annotationView"
    var view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        if view == nil {
            view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        }
        view?.displayPriority = .required
    } else {
        if view == nil {
            view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        }
    }
    view?.annotation = annotation
    view?.canShowCallout = true
    return view
}
```

Comment: It's actually probably a bug from Apple, as the default display priority should be `.required` (but it's apparently not!)

Comment: (BTW you should not refer to another answer as "above" or "below", as their order changes depending on their ratings. Instead, you should write "NiltiakSivad's solution". I'll edit your answer accordingly.)

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer from Leszek Szary is correct.

But there is some fineprint. Sometimes `MKMarkerAnnotationView`s are not rendered, even if

```
view.displayPriority = .required
```

is set.

What you are seeing is a combination of different rules.

1. `MKAnnotationViews` are rendered from top to bottom of the map. (It doesn't matter where north is).
2. If `MapKit` decides to draw overlapping `MKAnnotationViews`, then the `MKAnnotationView` nearer to the bottom is drawn on top (because it's drawn later)
3. Not only `MKAnnotationViews`, also titles rendered below `MKMArkerAnnotationViews` need space. The rendering of those titles is influenced by `markerView.titleVisibility`. If `markerView.titleVisibility` is set to `.visible` (instead of the default `.adaptive`), then this title is stronger than a `MarkerAnnotationView` that is rendered later, even if the later `MarkerAnnotationView` has a `displayPriority = .required`. The `MarkerAnnotationView` nearer to the bottom is not rendered.
4. This even happens if the `MarkerAnnotationView` nearer to the top has a low `displayPriority`. So a `MarkerAnnotationView` with low `displayPriority` and `.titleVisibility = .visible` can make a `MarkerAnnotationView` nearer to the bottom with `displayPriority = .required` disappear.

I am not aware of a documentation of this behaviour. This is the result of my experiments with iOS 12. My description is sipmplified.

Answer (score 6):

I was setting `annotationView.displayPriority = .required` only when the MKMarkAnnotationView was first allocated. Normally thats all you should need to do, but setting it each time the cell was reused fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

I was experiencing a similar issue. My best guess is that it has something to do with how iOS 11 detects pin collisions. Implementing a custom annotation view or reverting to use the iOS 10 pin fixed the problem for me.

For example, implementing the following should fix your code:

```
class MultiMapVC: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       mapView.delegate = self    
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
       guard let annotation = annotation as? MKPointAnnotation else { return nil }

       let identifier = "pin-marker"
       var view: MKAnnotationView

       if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView {
           dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
           view = dequeuedView
       } else {
           view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
       }
       return view
   }
}
```

If this doesn't work, there is a `displayPriority` property that is worth looking into as it is responsible for helping to determine when pins should be hidden/shown at different zoom levels. More info at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/2867298-displaypriority

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works!  One thing I noticed is that these pins aren't selectable.

Answer (score 2):

I was seeing a similar problem with Xcode 10, and iOS 12+ as my deployment target. A post from an Apple staffer (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/92839) recommends toggling the `.isHidden` property on the dequeued marker. That has improved things but has not completely solved the problem.

```
result?.isHidden = true
result?.isHidden = false
return result
```