# Disappearing markers during clustering in MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I have problem with [clustering in MapKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/decluttering_a_map_with_mapkit_annotation_clustering).
I try to build clustering with at least two different types of clusters like e-scooters and cars (defined by `clusteringIdentifier` - [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/2867297-clusteringidentifier)). But a problem occurs while two elements with different `clusteringIdentifier` are very close to each others - one of them just disappear.

[Here you can find preview of the problem](http://77.55.209.235/shared/ios_clustering.mp4)

Docs says that clustering is based on `collisionMode`. I assume that whenever there is collision between two markers of the same type - they are clustered.
The problem occurs when collision is detected between elements with different `clusteringIdentifier`. In that case markers just disappears (the reason is that `collisionMode` is turned on).

I tried to change collisionMode to .none, but clustering stop working in that case.

Is there any way to achieve clustering working with different `clusterIdentifiers` without disappearing?

Comment: rendering of AnnotationViews of clusters behaves exactly like rendering normal annotationViews. You find the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49020023/mapkit-annotations-disappearing/55663218#55663218

Comment: @GerdCastan migrating to MKMarkerAnnotationView solved problem! Big thanks!